# Changing internal class to public (CIL, Mono.Cecil)

Tags: c#, cil, mono.cecil

Is there a way to get interclass's type via CIL and change It to public?

```
AssemblyDefinition x = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly("x.dll");
TypeDefinition type = x.MainModule.GetType("Class");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AssemblyDefinition adef = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly("x.dll");
TypeDefinition tdef = adef.MainModule.GetType("Class");
tdef.IsPublic = true;
adef.MainModule.Write("x_updated.dll");
```